# hiding columns of a datagrid (asp.net/c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, visible

Hey, I am trying to make my datagrid printable. To do this, I am trying to hide the final 4 columns. I have a printable button that I would like to when clicked, make those last 4 columns disappear. I have so far failed to make this work.

I have tried:

```
 ProductsGrid.Columns[6].ControlStyle.Width = -1;
```

and

```
 ProductsGrid.Columns[6].Visible = false;
```

Note: these columns do have data in them. Perhaps that is part of my issue. Also, I need the headers of the columns to disappear.

Thanks for any tips.

EDIT: I am making them invisible in my button click command. I am not using generated columns, so I think that is set to false. I got a bit fed up with this issue and left work, and won't be back till mid next week, so I might have to hold off finding the solution till then. Thanks for the comments everyone, I will look it over soon. Sorry, I can't give more feedback in a timely fashion.

Edit x2: Do have I have to handle it in some sort of postback or something?

Comment: ProductsGrid.Columns[6].Visible = false; should be working.  I'm not 100% sure, but I think  you have to call DataBind() again to update it.  Unless you re-bind the data, the controls are not updated on the page.  (I'm setting this as a comment rather than an answr instead of an answer because I'm not 100% sure, and not at my Dev PC to test it.)

Comment: Where and when do you hide your columns? Making them invisible should work(without rebinding).  Are you autogenerating the columns?

Comment: If that fails, it shouldn't be too difficult to just produce a second page for printing by copying and pasting code, then remove the columns from the print page in the markup, and link to it with a "Print-friendly version " link.  Or you could set the the header and cells of the table to a css class called "noprint" and have a css for display and one  for printing, setting visible to false in the second css...

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Tim.  You really shouldn't need to rebind, and the code you're using should work.  Good thought on the AutoGenerateColumns property...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have AutoGenerateColumns="True", then it does not work to make them invisible by simply set visible=False, because [automatically generated bound column fields are not added to the Columns collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns%28VS.80%29.aspx).

VB.Net, but i think you get the idea:

```
Private Sub setPrinterView()
  For Each tr As TableRow In DirectCast(Me.GridView1.Controls(0), Table).Rows
      For i As Int32 = 1 To 4
          If tr.Cells.Count - i < 0 Then Exit For
          tr.Cells(tr.Cells.Count - i).Visible = False
      Next
   Next
End Sub
```

If AutogenerateColumns is set to False you only need to make the Columns invisible without rebinding the Grid.